# PHP ROUND vs Javascript ROUND

Tags: javascript, php

I found a very strange issue, the issue is the ROUND method in PHP and Javascript the calculation results are not the same!?

See the following example:

PHP

```
echo round(175.5); // 176
echo round(-175.5); // -176
```

Javascript

```
console.log(Math.round(175.5)); // 176
console.log(Math.round(-175.5)); // -175 <-why not -176!!??
```

anyone know why? and how to make Javascript and PHP the same results?

Comment: Why is this strange to you?

Comment: [javascript vs php rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437062/javascript-vs-php-rounding) and [floating point percision in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Comment: Plz check the PHP_ROUND_ constants http://it1.php.net/manual/en/math.constants.php and by the way javascript is not php.

Comment: I think but i'm not sure that is a math different between languages ! In math, -175.5 will be rounded -175.

Comment: @Soheyl On math, It depends also on your given system what is possible  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770992/int-max-size-for-32bit-system

Comment: To begin with, [PHP round()](http://php.net/round) has a parameter with up to 4 algorithms to pick from.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions thx for the link, I mean by math's logic and not a program, and I mean the JavaScript has more correct return than PHP in this example :)

Comment: @Soheyl Ok, but i was more point to on witch hardware runs software. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#IEEE_754:_floating_point_in_modern_computers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not an issue, it is well [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

> If the fractional portion is exactly 0.5, the argument is rounded to
>   the next integer in the direction of +∞.  Note that this differs from
>   many languages' round() functions, which often round this case to the
>   next integer away from zero, instead (giving a different result in the
>   case of negative numbers with a fractional part of exactly 0.5).

If you want the same behaviour on Javascript, I would use

```
var n = -175.5;
var round = Math.round(Math.abs(n))*(-1)
```

Answer (score 5):

A quick solution is to do the following:

```
echo round(-175.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); // -175
```

There are other modes to choose from:

1. `PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP` - *default*
2. `PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN`
3. `PHP_ROUND_HALF_ODD`

See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) for more information.

This function will behave the same as in [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript):

```
function jsround($float, $precision = 0){
  if($float < 0){
     return round($float, $precision, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
  }

  return round($float, $precision);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer is also very useful but can only choose one :(.

Comment: No worries, you wanted the value of `-176` preferably, this only answers how to get the same value controlled from [tag:PHP].

Answer (score 2):

```
console.log(Math.round(175.5)); // 176
console.log(Math.round(-175.5)); // -175 <-why not -176!!??
```

175.5 its round value 176 it's value increasing.

-175.5 round value is -175. Because when I round -175.5 then it also increasing that means -175>-176.

Answer (score 1):

To control it more use `ceil` and `floor` for rounding. That way you can choose which way to round

Answer (score 0):

Or... if you wanted JavaScript to behave the same as PHP, use this:

```
function phpRound(number) {
  if(number < 0)
    return 0 - Math.round(0 - number);
  return Math.round(number);
}
```