# Why getdate(1500000000) returns July 7 2017 while getdate(2500000000) returns February 13 1913

Tags: php, date, datetime, getdate

The question is simple is this a bug or I'm missing something here, the fact is that a bigger value for getdate returns an earlier date. What's wrong there??

Comment: Do you know anything about binary numbers, 32 bit ints etc?

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: Nothing at all, I'm asking because I have no idea why is that happening and I'm afraid that my project could go to hell because I use unix time stamps a lot

Comment: There's a [note here in the PHPP docs explaining unix timestamp date range](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2,500,000,000` exceeds the maximum value for a 32 bit integer.

I didn't know the answer ahead of time. These are the resources I used to figure this out: 
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php
[INT max size for 32bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770992/int-max-size-for-32bit-system)

Comment: Yup! I learned that after reading [John3136](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43531455/1370831)'s answer and then edited mine to remove the inaccuracy. You're quick though ;)

Comment: Ok, so how should I deal with it, will my project eventually crash??

Comment: @Marange - either switch to 64-bit PHP, or use DateTime objects instead of unix timestamps

Answer (score 2):

2500000000 = 0x9502F900 = 1001 0101 0000 0010 1111 1001 0000 0000

i.e. On a 32 bit system, the sign bit is set, so you've actually got a negative number. Since the universe started in 1970 (according to unix), a date in 1913 is a clear symptom of a negative timestamp.